# Microsoft Azure app outputs error when it receives a long URL. How do I fix this?

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

I'm using the App Service to host a wordpress blog. When I search using my site's search engine I receive an Azure error. I'm assuming because the URL is too long as a safety feature to prevent injection attacks.

The error message is: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: I found this: http://andredublin.github.io/.net/2014/06/26/large-query-string-values-and-azure.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stealing part of this answer from @Shirin.

1. Open your Azure Portal. Go to App Service which you are using to
   host word press. Click on Advanced Tools.
2. Click Go. It will open Kudu App Service.
3. Click on Debug console >> CMD.
4. From the top explorer navigation, go to site/wwwroot and find your web.config file.
5. Click edit
6. It will open editor for you to edit your web.config file. Add security > requestFiltering > requestLimits.maxQueryString element. Also add system.web > httpRuntime.maxQueryStringLength element. I am giving example below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength = "10000" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="10000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have an Azure App Service that handles AspNetCore.SignalR Hub calls requiring authentication. Works fine on local machine or if authentication is disabled. Problem is GET wss:// calls include an access_token parameter that can cause the URL to exceed standard Azure limit with a non-specific error message. As you suggest, adding your web.config solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to add a custom mime type into Azure App Service web.config file for the type of file you are searching.

1. Open your Azure Portal.
   Go to App Service which you are using to host word press.
   Click on Advanced Tools.
   [image]
2. Click Go. It will open Kudu App Service.
3. Click on Debug console >> CMD.
4. From the top explorer navigation, go to site/wwwroot and find your
   web.config file.
   [image]
5. Click edit pencil icon.
6. It will open editor for you to edit your web.config file. Add your
   mime type inside staticContent element. I am giving example below.

> 

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="wp-content/themes/move-service/assets/video" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".extension" mimeType="your_files_url" />
```

Comment: I think I am on the right track right now. You pointed me to the right config file -- but I think the settings are actually a security setting as described in this article. http://andredublin.github.io/.net/2014/06/26/large-query-string-values-and-azure.html


    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="10000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>